# Git log – add separator between unrelated histories, especially for --oneline

Tags: git, git-log

I work with Git almost every day. One of the most popular subcommands is `git log`. For better view I use slightly extended version of
    `git log --decorate --oneline --graph`:

`log --graph --decorate --date=relative --pretty=format:'%C(yellow bold)%h %C(green dim)%ad %C(blue)%an %C(auto)%s %d'`

Lets create a simple repo with two roots – unrelated branches.

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m"asdf 1"
git commit --allow-empty -m"zxcv 2"
git commit --allow-empty -m"qwer 3"
git co --orphan another
git commit --allow-empty -m"uiop 8"
git commit --allow-empty -m"hjkl 9"
git nl --all
```

where `nl` is a short name of *nicelog* and is aliased to the second command presented earlier.
[image]
At first glance I see branch *another* is descender of branch *master* but that is wrong. As you can see on a next picture
[image]
command: `log --graph --decorate --date=relative --pretty=format:'%C(yellow bold)%h %C(green dim)%ad %C(blue)%an <%ae> %C(auto)%d %GS %n%w(0,3,3)%s%n%+b'`

#### The question

How to make `git log` add separator between unrelated histories? Like that:

```
 * f949c4f 6 minutes ago kyb hjkl 9  (HEAD -> another)
 * 5dea811 6 minutes ago kyb uiop 8 
 --
 * ca006bf 7 minutes ago kyb qwer 3  (master)
 * 73056fd 7 minutes ago kyb zxcv 2 
 * e0d91c1 7 minutes ago kyb asdf 1
```

#### Workaround

One obvious way is to use multiline format like:

`log --graph --decorate --date=relative --pretty=format:'%C(yellow bold)%h %C(green dim)%ad %C(blue)%an <%ae> %C(auto)%d %GS %n%w(0,3,3)%s'`

note `%n` in format string.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get what you want.  If you'd like to take a stab at writing code for Git that would do this, clone one of the read-only clones of the Git source—the most obvious one is https://github.com/git/git—and have at it.

(This really would be nice, and I've wanted it now and then, but the difficulty in implementing it will become clear and I've never wanted it *enough*. :-)  Unrelated histories aren't all that common, so its usefulness is pretty limited.)